# can I have an even texture distribution over a facetted topology?

Tags: uv, text-object, texture-coordinates, distort

Dear 3D artists I want to display a Video as an image texture but I want the texture to be flat. Unfortunately the Video always gets distorted. [image: distorted texture]I [image: test image]think it depends on the topology of the object where the texture should be projected on. I tried all possible settings but can't achieve the appropriate solution. Do you have an advise for me? I would be very thankful.

[image: topology]
[image: node tree]

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to get the result because:

- Your image is not square
- Your object has uneven dimensions
- Your object (probably) has uneven scale

So what you can do to walkaround these issues?

1. Go to edit mode, select all screen faces and in top view (<kbd>Num 7</kbd>) press <kbd>U</kbd> ⇾ **project from view (bounds)**
2. In material, connect UV from texture coordinates.

In this way, Video/image will perfectly fit screen size, and all uneven scales of object and image will be ignored.